# variable <div> background, php

Tags: php, html, background

I want to dynamically assign a background url to the page based upon certain variables.

Is this possible with php?  If so, how?  I have assigned a number of divs with Ids.

Comment: Yes this is possible with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <? 
 if ($var=='someval'){
   echo<<<style
   <style>
    #d1{
       somestyle;
    }
   </style>
style;
 }
 else if ($val=='someothetval'){
   echo<<<style
   <style>
    #d1{
       somestyle;
    }
   </style>
style;
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i'll end up doing something similar to this.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change the div background without refreshing the page, you need to use Javascript. But if you want to refresh the page, there are many different ways in PHP to do what you ask.

For example you can store a value in the `$_SESSION` array and change it on every load, then choose a background of an array of backgrounds.

Also you can return a random background on every load using the [rand](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php) function.

Comment: I want to assign a background to the div at the time the server dispatches the page to the user.  I don't the user to change it.  Simply dynamically assign a different background based upon a stored variable.

Comment: Then use the '$_SESSION' array and store the visits of the user to the page. With this value you will be able to set a different background on every load.